# JAVA classpath pass file as command line argument

Tags: java, file, command-line-arguments

I have a program which is located in

say

```
$A430CLASS/com.airbus.adcsip.batch.GlobalReportBatch
```

**$A430CLASS is the path where my class file is present.**

i want to run it through shell script so i entered following command :

```
java -classpath $A430CLASS/com.airbus.adcsip.batch.GlobalReportBatch $A430CONF/batch.properties
```

**$A430CONF is the path where the batch.properties file is present.
GlobalReportBatch is my class file name**
As you can see i want to pass this batch.properties file as argument to my java program. but when i run my script it tries to replace "." in batch.props file to "/" it gives me `NoClassDefFound` error.

Comment: I tried using quotes.. but no luck... same error.. :(

Comment: I don't see a classpath actually in your statement above.

Comment: Separate the classes in classpath by a semi-colon `;`

Comment: what if, `java -classpath . $A430CLASS/com.airbus.adcsip.batch.GlobalReportBatch $A430CONF/batch.properties`

Comment: Hovercraft is right : "$A430CLASS/com.airbus.adcsip.batch.GlobalReportBatch" is interpreted as the classpath and that's while the last argument is interpreted as the class.

Comment: There is only one class i.e. GlobalReportBatch and the other part i.e. "$A430CONF/batch.properties" is argument to my program

Comment: @DattaprasadPatil: but what package is the main program in?

Answer (score 4):

What you put after the `-classpath` option must be a list of directories and JAR files, separated by `:` (on Unix-like operating systems) or `;` (on Windows).

Look at what you are passing:

`-classpath $A430CLASS/com.airbus.adcsip.batch.GlobalReportBatch`

Remove the slash `/` between `$A430CLASS` and your class name; replace it by a space:

`-classpath $A430CLASS com.airbus.adcsip.batch.GlobalReportBatch`

So the entire line becomes:

```
java -classpath $A430CLASS com.airbus.adcsip.batch.GlobalReportBatch $A430CONF/batch.properties
```

Comment: actually $A430CLASS and com....GlobalReportBatch is related.. consider $A430CLASS as my home directory... so is your syntax right?

Comment: @Datta: again you've not told us your package structure yet.

Comment: my class file is in $A430CLASS/com/airbus/adcsip/batch/ where my class GlobalReportBatch is located...  $A430CLASS - is my variable set to some xyz path so it becomes xyz path/com/airbus/.....

Comment: @Datta: but again, please tell us ***what is the package structure?*** I'm not sure how to ask this any clearer sort of way. What is on the package statement at the top of your java file?

Comment: @ Hovercraft :  sry mate coudnt understand your query... :(

Comment: @Datta: at the top of the java file, there is often a package statement. It might read `package com.airbus.adcsip.batch;` or somesuch. I'm asking you to tell us exactly what is on that line.

Comment: its same "package com.airbus.adcsip.batch" i hope i have answered your question...

Comment: Does the directory that `$A430CLASS` points to contain your package directory hierarchy, with your class files? So, the directory should contain a subdirectory `com/airbus/adcsip/batch`, and that directory should contain your class file `GlobalReportBatch.class`.

Comment: @DattaprasadPatil Try @Jesper answer: `java -classpath $A430CLASS com.airbus.adcsip.batch.GlobalReportBatch $A430CONF/batch.properties` It should work.

Comment: Still getting `NoClassDefFoundError`? For which class? Your `GlobalReportBatch` class? Then there must still be something wrong with how you specify the classpath, or the directory structure isn't there, or the class file is not in the right place.

Comment: I have checked the class file location almost 100 times now.. everything is at right place.. even i am confused y is it happening..

Comment: What do you see when you enter the command: `echo $A430CLASS`?

Comment: @Jesper Sorry for late reply - $A430CLASS shows "/A430_VAL/server/WEB-INF/classes".. where all the class files are located..