# Class loading error in Jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, database-connection

I just created a Class Jdbc when i tried to run an error is shown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Jdbc
```

Here's the code

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Jdbc {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ims","","");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        DatabaseMetaData meta=con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet r=meta.getTables(null,null,"%",null);
        String tableNames="";
        while(r.next()){
        tableNames=r.getString(3);
        System.out.println(tableNames);
        }
        }catch (Exception e){}}}
```

Comment: no need to call `.newInstance` while loading the class. And set the classpath properly to mysql Driver.

Comment: Did you compile the code with javac before trying to run it? This is a generic error unrelated to jdbc.

Comment: then i have to specify return value

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380681/jdbc-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-com-mysql-jdb

Comment: ya joni its compiled perfectly but not running

Comment: tastao i already add mysql jar file to class path

Comment: Add your class Jdbc to classpath see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with mysql jar but your own class "Jdbc" is not on classpath, add it to classpath.

If you are running from console add .; to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely that your program is not able to find the class 
Place the mysql jdbc driver `mysql-connector-java-5.x.x.jar` in `classpath` and then check.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 quick fixes would be either

1) Pass the classspath to the execution `java -classpath mysql.jar`

See

[JAVA classpath pass file as command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709796/java-classpath-pass-file-as-command-line-argument)

2) Put the [mysql jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in your JRE's `ext`directory. [Details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html).

You probably want to put your class in a package since you're using the default package. Also an IDE such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/) could help you for convienience. You don't tell us your execution environment or build path and your result may depend on if you're running the program from the command line, from a runnable jar or from an IDE.

I use the Eclipse Juno IDE so I don't need to worry about setting my classpath. For Ubuntu and MS-Windows, Eclipse IDE is a development environment you might want to use.

Comment: i just use text editor only for jdbc demo

Comment: @Gaurav Ok, to run your program, first make sure you actually have the jar from mysql or you can get it from the link listed here.

Answer (score 0):

!. Make sure that the jar is in your class path
2. If not then download it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Comment: i got the solution i just add class file path in my class path nor problem with connector thanks every one